# Retrieving the value of textarea in a v-for array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

Considering this scenario

At .vue `template`

```
<div v-for="(tweet, index) in tweets">
  <div class="each_tweet">
    <textarea v-on:keyup="typing(index)"
              placeholder="What's happening now">{{ tweet.content }}</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

At .vue `<script>`

```
export default {
  methods: {
   typing: function(index) {
    console.log(this.tweets[index])//How to get the value of textarea 
   }
 }, 
   data: function () {
    return {
      tweets: [{id: 0, content: ""},
               {id: 1, content: ""}]
    }
  }

}
```

My question is:

1) Is there a way to sync the value of the textarea with each tweet object's content? The value refers to the innerText of the textarea.

2) Is there a way to get the value of the textarea at the method "typing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Multiline-text):

> You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on
> form input and textarea elements.

For example:

```
<div v-for="(tweet, index) in tweets">
  <div class="each_tweet">
    <textarea v-on:keyup="typing(index)"
              v-model="tweet.content"
              placeholder="What's happening now"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! didn't realise I can use v-model this way. I spent so much time thinking the jquery or getelementbyid way.